# Model fails individual predictions but gets the total right

Tags: r, classification, probability, random-forest, prediction

So here's the situation.

I have a binary classification problem (lets say, whether or not an observation will experience action x). I train a random forest model on a training set where about 50% have done action x and 50% have not. I test the model on a test set (again, about 50% did action x, 50% did not), and its about 85% or so accurate and has an overall error rate of about 15% or so. A year passes and I get new data and I want to see how the model performed. It predicted that about 9% of the data will experience action x. 9% of the data did in fact experience action x but it failed to accurately predict the individual observations that would experience action x. In order words, the individual observations it predicted would experience action x did not actually experience action x. And the individual observations that did in fact experience action x, the model did not predict it so.

So essentially what does it mean that the model gets the aggregate correct but fails to make accurate predictions at the micro level? Is there a mathematical explanation on how this might occur? Maybe something to do with aggregating the probabilities? Is it still useful at predicting totals?

Comment: This sounds like you need to **analyse** your specific case as to what the model found to be "true" and what the actual 9% looked like.
Maybe there is a time component in your model wich it couldn't fit; maybe it's another problem. Noone knows. I'd consider the 9% = 9% to be somewhat random, unless there is a justifiable reason.

Another thing is that you may want to let the random forest emit probabilities instead of hard classes and examine the ROC-Curve for anything special going on in the test data vs. the new data.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming so it is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you have questions about statistical models, you should be asking them at [stats.se] where such questions are on topic.